# Rails - chain 'where' scopes with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

I can chain scopes like so:

```
scoped = User.where(sex: 'F')
scoped = scoped.where(color: 'blue')
```

ActiveRecord generates this SQL for the 1st line:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."sex" = 'F'
```

And this SQL for the 2nd line:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."sex" = 'F' AND "users"."color" = 'blue'
```

While keeping the initial query so it's built over 2 lines how can I change it from `AND` to `OR` so the end result looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."sex" = 'F' OR "users"."color" = 'blue'
```

Comment: Agreed with Logan's answer. Try squeel or arel for richer syntax. We use squeel,  so far so good.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reason you need to build this over multiple lines?

Comment: I need to build this on multiple lines because i'm iterating over an array of keys in an `hstore` attribute and for each key I want to find all records that are missing the key outright or, if they have the key that it is not `nil` or `""`. That's a loop.Then I want to extend it with an `OR` clause to select all records where the hstore attribute itself is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Without extensions, this is currently impossible with Rails unless you use raw SQL:

```
User.where('sex = ? OR color = ?', 'F', 'blue')
```

[In Rails 5, these types of ORs will be supported out of the box.](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052)

Comment: I need to build this over multiple lines. How can I use raw SQL to build this over multiple lines? Basically keep add two queries together via `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `squeel` gem, you can implement this like so:

```
User.where(
  { sex: 'F' } |
  { color: 'blue' }
)
```

However, since it sounds like you need to build the query dynamically, I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
queries = [
  "sex = 'F'",
  "color = 'blue'"
]

User.where(queries.join(" OR "))
```

With this method, you can dynamically add as many queries as you need to the `queries` array. Obviously, you'll have to write the queries in raw SQL but this is the only option I'm aware of for accomplishing this with ActiveRecord.

### UPDATE

To answer @Thomas question in the comments:

> I'm wondering if there is a way to utilize join data with this. Like
> user.sex instead of sex.

```
queries = [
  "users.sex = 'F'",
  "color = 'blue'"
]

Car.joins(:user).where(queries.join(" OR "))
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to utilize join data with this.  Like user.sex instead of sex.

Comment: @Thomas answer expanded for your question.